# variable changing property is not working in dart programming

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

```
void main() {
  var a,b;
  print("Enter the value of a & b : ");
  a=int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  b=int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());`enter code here`

  print("Addition: ${a+b}");
  print("Subtraction: ${a-b}");
  print("Multiplication: ${a*b}");
  print("Division: ${a/b}");
  print("Mod: ${a%b}");
}
```

**above code I have using for dart. my problem is whenever I pretend to change the variable to a integer or double value not allowing to run:**

```
Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't  b=int. parse(stdin. read Line Sync());
```

above kind of error throwing. please can anyone help me to understand. because maybe I have made a wrong input or missed something. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a error related to the new [Null Safety](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety) in Flutter, your variable is nullable because it has the "?" after "String". You just have to add a "!" after the variable that's throwing the error.